# Track if bulk Async calls are finished

Tags: 2010, javascript, csom, visual-web-part, ajax

Environment SP 2010

I am creating Visual Webpart. And on `btnAdd` button click adding a row with 5 controls in it using js. On button Save click I am saving those 5 fields to a SharePoint list. I can have any no of such rows available. I am storing ItemID's of those to a hidden control to read it at server side.

The problem here is after this async ajax calls I am calling serverclick method. By the time these controls gets lost on postback.

How can I track if all ajax calls are successfully executed, So I can call code behind event?

```
  function createListItem(webUrl, listName, itemProperties, index, success, failure) {

    $.ajax({
        url: webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName,
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d);
            document.getElementById('<%=hdnComponentIDs.ClientID%>').value += data.d.Id + ",";
            componentCounter++;
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data.responseJSON.error);
        }
    });
}
```

call to the above method :

```
createListItem(siteUrl, 'CAPEXObjective', alldata, index,
               function (data) {
                        componentCounter++;
                        console.log("Component Created");
               },
               function (error) {
                       console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                        }
               );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use JQuery Deferred & Promise methods. Basically your AJAX call will return a **promise** and you can call our server button click event after the deffered action is resolved.
See this [api documentation](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)  and read this good [post](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/) about the same.

```
    /* ajax calls returns promise by default*/
    function doAjaxCall(){
            return $.ajax({/*your ajax call configuration here */});
    }

     //in you main code 
      doAjaxCall().then(function(data){
                        //success handler 
                 }).fail(function(error){
                     //fail handler
                 });
```

Comment: You mean I should add my ajax call inside `var d = $.Deferred();` & `return d.promise();`

Comment: updated answer with a small sample

Comment: See ``$.when`` : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/